# How can a caster cast personal spells on other creatures?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, targeting

Is there a class feature or magic item that enables a caster to cast on another creature a spell with a range of personal?

For example, the spell [*shield*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/shield.html) is a wonderful spell but rarely are folks other than arcane casters able to benefit from it.

The only method I know of is a caster having a [familiar and sharing spells](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/classes/wizard.html#familiar-share-spells) with it, which in this case does not help.

Comment: I expect you are correct, but I really hope there is a way to have intelligent items cast the low level buff spells and save my action economy.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Your revision is good

Comment: @Fering may we know what class is this for? Wizard, Sorcerer, Witch, Magus?

Comment: @ShadowKras Hoping that I can apply it to intelligent items that have their own castable spells and have them as first round low level buffs. But really any support caster would love to have this ability.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to get that is to get [infused extract](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/infusion/) from an Alchemist.

Also note that on the same page you can find this extract from the FAQ:

> Can I use the infusion discovery to create an infused extract of a personal-range formula (such as true strike), which someone else can drink?
>
> Yes, you can. The design team may decide to close this loophole in the next printing of the Advanced Player’s Guide.

Comment: This can also be usee with the tumor familiar to improve action economy.

Comment: Combined with the [poisoner's gloves](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/wondrousItems/hands.html#Poisoner's-Gloves) the alchemist or investigator can affect another creature with it without any action necessary by the recipient.

Comment: Note that despite the comment about closing it, they never actually did.

Answer (score 8):

There are a variety of ways to get a Personal range effect onto a non-spellcaster, though most of them require a fair amount of preparation prior to use.

The first instinct is to go with potions, but unfortunately [Personal range spells are specifically diallowed](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html#creating-potions):

> Spells with a range of personal cannot be made into potions.

Next most obvious would be wands or staffs, but that requires the user to have ranks in Use Magic Device. That may be a deal breaker, depending on your build, and only partially satisfies the requirement of "without needing to cast them yourself" since you don't actually need levels in a spellcasting class.

There is a divine spell that gets you halfway there: *[imbue with spell ability](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/imbueWithSpellAbility.html#imbue-with-spell-ability)*. For an arcane caster, without a scroll and ranks in Use Magic Device, that option is out of reach. A divine caster could give a martial character *[divine favor](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/divineFavor.html#divine-favor)*, which isn't too shabby.

That leaves some item that stores a spell for the wearer to use, such as a *[ring of spell storing](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/rings.html#ring-of-spell-storing-minor)*. The caster needs to take the time to cast the relevant spells into the ring, but thereafter, the wearer can cast those spells themselves. This method has a large up-front cost but the rings are reusable.

The idea of having an intelligent item cast the spells itself is a good one, but it doesn't work by RAW. The Personal range spells would affect the item itself and not its wielder because the item is the caster. That said, the GM can always decide otherwise if they're so inclined.

Comment: Spells in wands and staves are *cast*, per the spell-completion rules, so strictly speaking it doesn’t really satisfy “without needing to cast them yourself” even partially (still probably worth mentioning, though).

Comment: I figured I could sneak it in under the guise of not needing caster levels to use them.

Comment: If you figure a way to give a feat to your familiar, with the teamwork share spell you could have the familiar to cast the spell from a wand and split the duration between both of you.

Comment: This is already possible with an eidolon or animal companion, as long as they can spell trigger the wand.

Comment: Note that many classes that don't normally get a familiar can gain one through one of the archetypes provided by the Familiar Folio, like the Chosen One Paladin.

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question. I am looking for ways that would allow a spellcaster (either by class or magic item) to cast a personal spell onto someone who is NOT the original caster.

Comment: You may want to clarify your question, then. It's currently framed from the perspective of the spell recipient and not the caster. Even with that change, a *ring of spell storing* is your only hope.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to include the few archetypes that do things like this, even if just for subsets of [personal] spells; as examples, [Brown-Fur Transmuters](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/archetypes/paizo-arcanist-archetypes/brown-fur-transmuter/) at level 9 can share personal transmutation spells; [Sensei](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/sensei/) [Qinggong](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/qinggong-monk/) Monks can share a few, like True Strike, at level 6.

Answer (score 3):

If the spell's effects are at least in part harmful, and it is 6th level or less, you can store it in a *Greater Glyph of Warding* (or the regular version if it's 3rd or less).  This covers "mixed bag" spells like *[Tenser's Transformation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/transformation/)*, [*Psychic Asylum*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/psychic-asylum/), [*Life Conduit*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/life-conduit/), and [*Contact Other Plane*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/contact-other-plane/).

If your GM allows 3.5 material you can combine this with the prestige class Spellguard of the Silverymoon to cover 'defensive' spells as well, though that is more strictly defined.

Answer (score 2):

One of the other players in one my games figured out this method:

The target of the spell requires the [bonded mind](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/bonded-mind-teamwork) feat.

The caster of the spell requires bonded mind and [shared spells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/share-spells-teamwork/), as well as the ability to share spells with a familiar.

This allows you to cast personal spells with target You on allies with the bonded mind feat as a touch spell.

There is a spell called [Coordinated Effort](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Coordinated%20Effort) which would make it so your target doesnt even need to take the bonded mind feat. However its not on the cleric or wizard spell list so most likely you would have to UMD a wand of it or use a magic item.

Using [improved shared spells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-share-spells/) generally does not help due to spreading out the duration.

Answer (score 1):

The methods currently mentioned by Karalzarath are as far as I know are the only supported mechanisms in Pathfinder which would let an individual get the benefit of a personal spell without being able to cast it themselves (those being the use of a wand or other spell completion item and UMD, a [ring of spell storing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/#TOC-Ring-of-spell-Storing) or something that provides the same effect like the [Vibrant Purple Prism ioun stone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/vibrant-purple-prism-ioun-stone), and the [*Imbue with Spell Ability*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/imbue-with-spell-ability/) spell family. However, all of these require actions on the part of the subject so don't conserve your precious action economy.)

Alternatively, if you're willing to look further afield, the **Player's Guide To Faerun** manual for running Forgotten Realms in 3.5e includes the class [**Spellguard of Silverymoon**](http://dnd.arkalseif.info/classes/spellguard-of-silverymoon/index.html), which is a full casting progression 5-level prestige class with the following special ability at 4th level:

> **Spellguard (Su):** The Spellguard was originally formed to protect High Lady Alustriel from personal attacks. Though that purpose has largely become secondary to defending the city, spellguards still receive some training in serving as bodyguards. At 4th level, the spellguard of Silverymoon may cast any personal-range defensive arcane spell on another character with a touch. For this purpose, a defensive spell is one that improves AC, increases a saving throw modifier, or grants additional hit points (either by healing wounds or by bestowing temporary hit points).

Which allows you to cast a limited subset of personal range spells directly as touch spells, instead. If your GM permits you could translate the class into Pathfinder, presumably stripping out all the Silverymoon-specific special features it has.

Answer (score 1):

In 3.5 you can take the Master specialist abjurer. (there is some posibilities for converting prestige classes to pathfinder i think)

http://therafim.wikidot.com/master-specialist

On 10th level you get Major School Esoterica

Abjuration: When casting an abjuration spell that normally has a range of personal, you can instead choose to cast it as a touch spell that affects a single creature. When casting an abjuration spell that is an emanation centered on you, you can instead choose to cast it as a touch spell that emanates from the touched creature.

It only works for Abjuration spells that are personal. But Shield is included in that. however, i would suggest that you use your standard action to cast something a little more effective than shield if you are going to buff someone at level 14. (think that is the earliest you can get this, unless you take something to get around the requirements of the prestige class)

Answer (score 0):

Magic Jar is probably the only strictly-pathfinder-legal way. You could allow a wizard to possess you, then they cast self-buffs, then they return you to your body. Tada, self-buffs cast on you by them.

Comment: This is the thought I had when I read the question.

Answer (score 0):

### Casting *personal* spells on Intelligent magic items

> **Intelligent items can actually be considered creatures** because they have Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores.

This quote is all we need to target intelligent items with [Imbue with Spell Ability](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/imbueWithSpellAbility.html#imbue-with-spell-ability), or [Spellcasting Contract](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spellcasting-contract/) for followers of *Asmodeus*.

> Target creature touched;

However, being an arcane caster, you have no access to that spell. But that doesn't mean that it's impossible to obtain the ability to cast specific divine spells as an arcane caster. Here are a few options available:

- The [Pathfinder Savant prestige class](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/a-b/arcane-savant/) can pick spells from any class's spell list, thought it is treated as one spell levels higher.
- The [Daivrat prestigue class](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/daivrat/) can pick spells from any class's spell list, but if the spell is not on his list it is treated as two spell levels higher (4th level spell becomes 6th). 5 Levels in the class are enough.
- The [Razmiran Priest sorcerer bloodline](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/archetypes/paizo-sorcerer-archetypes/razmiran-priest/), at 9th level, will allow you to channel a divine magic item as if you were a divine caster by spending a spell slot one level higher than the one on the item. This would allow you to use a Staff or Wand charged with divine spells without spending charges.
- Both [Limited Wish](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/limitedWish.html#limited-wish) and [Wish](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/wish) will let you cast any cleric spell, given the spell restrictions.
- [Divine Knowledge mythic power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths-paizo-inc/archmage#TOC-Divine-Knowledge-Ex-) from the [Archmage Path](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths-paizo-inc/archmage/) will let you learn 1st to 3rd level spells from the cleric or druid spell lists. *Arcane Knowledge* does the same for divine casters and the wizard/sorcerer spell list.

Divine/Arcane knowledge won't let you cast *Imbue With Spell Ability*, but will let you directly grant up to 4th level spell to one item of your choice that was turned into an intelligent magic item by using [Impart Mind](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/impart-mind/).

And finally, [Spell-Capturing Gems](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gem-spell-capturing/) can store any spell cast on the caster that he successfully counterspell. The item is single-use and is pricey (2,500 gp), but it's a solution.

Some of these options can all be used on other creatures that are not intelligent magic items (say, your party members), so don't feel limited to using an intelligent item.

Comment: You have it backwards, I want the item to cast the spell on me